# How to query and login into the Bill.com API via Requests and Python?

Tags: python, rest, api

I'd like to query and login into [Bill.com via their REST API](http://developer.bill.com/api-documentation/overview/). In the past the below code worked, but now I'm getting a new error, which I'm unsure how to fix based on the [Bill.com API Login documentation](http://developer.bill.com/api-documentation/api/login).

```
login_end_point='https://api.bill.com/api/v2/Login.json?'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.get(login_end_point, params=login_params_dict).json()
```

In the past, this use to work perfectly, but now I' receiving the following error code:

```
{u'response_status': 1, u'response_message': u'Error', u'response_data': {u'error_message': u'HTTP Method not supported.', u'error_code': u'BDC_1340'}}
```

I've also tried the following, but I still receive an error:

Trying different login_end_point:

```
login_end_point='https://api.bill.com/api/v2/'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.get(login_end_point, params=login_params_dict).json()
```

Trying login_end_point and post instead of get:

```
login_end_point='https://api.bill.com/api/v2/'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.post(login_end_point, params=login_params_dict).json()
```

Both of these tries return this error:

```
{u'response_status': 1, u'response_message': u'Error', u'response_data': {u'error_message': u'API not supported.', u'error_code': u'BDC_1121'}}
```

I've also tried the following:

```
login_end_point= 'https://api.bill.com/api/v2/Login.json'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.post(login_end_point, params=login_params_dict).json()
```

but this returns the following error:

```
{u'response_status': 1, u'response_message': u'Error', u'response_data': {u'error_message': u'Invalid request. Check query string parameters.', u'error_code': u'BDC_1339'}}
```

Finally, I've tried the following using http instead of https

```
login_end_point= 'http://api.bill.com/api/v2/Login.json'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.post(login_end_point, params=login_params_dict).json()
```

But this returns the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.bill.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/Login.json?userName=%40Cue.com&devKey=01NZ&password=DoC&orgId=00(Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x106602b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you linked:

> Do not send the username and password as query parameters as it is not secure, i.e., don't pass your parameters as part of the URL ( /Login.json?userName=X&password=Y) nor pass the parameters as GET request.
>
> Instead, use POST instead of GET and store the parameters in the request body.
>
> For all Login calls, GET requests will be rejected as well as any POST requests that contain parameters in the URL instead of the request body.

You need to do a POST request and store login data in the request body.

In your code, you should pass login data as the `json` argument instead of `params`:

```
login_end_point= 'https://api.bill.com/api/v2/Login.json'
login_params_dict = {'userName': username, 'password': password, 'orgId': orgId, 'devKey': devKey}
result = requests.post(login_end_point, json=login_params_dict)
```

Note that if you're using an older version of requests (< 2.4.2), you should encode the data dict yourself:

```
result = requests.post(login_end_point, data=json.dumps(login_params_dict))
```

[Requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: I've tried your both of your solutions, but I receive the following error: "Missing parameter value for parameter: userName". This is a different error than before, but I'm not sure best way how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to send as formdata instead of json body!